# Marriage on standard visitor visa

Tags: standard-visitor-visas

Can I marry a british citizen  while I am in UK on standard visitor visa  though rules say I can't?

Comment: Why do you think you can do something the rules say you can't?

Comment: This sounds like a very complicated and expensive way to get banned from the UK.

Answer (score 2):

No you cannot. You need to apply for a Marriage Visa. A Visit Visa is for visits.